# How to properly index path in @RequestMapping which is a path for JsonNodeTree?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, microservices

I have a @RequestMapping that looks like this `"@RequestMapping("/text/{id_no}/{tempath}**")"`
Where tempath is the location of the file in a JsonNodeTree, which I am using below as

```
String path = "/" + tempath.toString();
return jsonNode.at(path).asText();".
```

It works perfectly fine when I have only one instance of a path like `"/text/5012394/time"`, but it shows an error when I try to put a path that looks like this (`"/text/5012394/timezones/0/time"`), where /timezones is an Object/Array in the JsonNode containing more elements. My opinion is that the error runs when I put an integer into the path, and the App doesn't know how to handle it, which I tried resolving with .toString(); but no luck.

Does anyone have an idea to fix this problem?

Comment: can you help us with the stack trace for the error you are getting?

Comment: You are getting error because you have / in the template. Request mapping wont be able to recognize resource path vs template difference. Send encoded template and then decode it for use.

Comment: @SantosshKumhar "Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat Nov 23 15:47:28 CET 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available" , I get the Whitelabel Error when accessing from browser, doesn't show an error in Eclipse tho.

Comment: @JUser Any idea how could I accomplish that for this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

As I said it , you are getting error because you have / in the template. Request mapping wont be able to recognize resource path vs template difference. Send encoded template and then decode it for use.
One way to solve it to base 64 encode the template and then decode it before you read template